# Couldn't use `return` in a constructor of a class which has a lambda field

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

The code looks like:

```java
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Test {
    Consumer<Integer> lambda = key -> {
    };

    public Test() {
        return; // NOTICE THIS LINE
    }
}
```

the build output would be like:

```
~\Test.java:7:19
java: variable key might not have been initialized
```

`java -version`:

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

`os ver`: Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.18363.1734]

[image]

Comment: yes, I given an smallest example above, but in our project there are some comparators with lambda compare functions not just `identity()`.

Comment: Just noticed the java version. Indeed I'm getting this error with a Java 8 (javac 1.8.0_292, from AdoptOpenJDK) compiler. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Indeed seems to be version-specific. No errors with Java 11

Comment: This is a [bug in java](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077667) but should have been fixed. Try updating Java version.

Comment: Just noticed the Java8 backport ticket was [closed as won't fix](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8171499). You might need to find a workaround (initialise lambda in the constructor) or upgrade to Java11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have rediscovered the [JDK-8077667](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077667) bug. As stated in the bug report it was fixed in version 9.